# How to put labels on plot markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plot-annotations

I am plotting a Precision/Recall Curve and want to put specific labels for each marker in the plot.

Here is the code that generates the plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.plot([0, 100], [94, 100], linestyle='--')

pyplot.xlabel("Recall")
pyplot.ylabel("Precision")
list_of_rec = [
99.96,99.96,99.96,99.96,99.96,99.96,99.8,98.25,96.59,93.37,83.74,63.53,48.72,25.05,10.7,4.27,0.73,0.23]

list_of_prec = [
94.12,94.12,94.12,94.12,94.12,94.12,94.42,95.14,95.92,96.57,97.33,98.26,98.72,99.0,99.0,99.17,99.75,99.19]

list_of_markers = [
    0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5
]

# plot the precision-recall curve for the model
pyplot.plot(list_of_rec, list_of_prec, marker='*', markersize=8)

pyplot.show()
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

For each of the markers in the plot (*) I want to label them with text from the `list_of_markers`. Don't seem to find an option to pass a list of text labels to the plot anywhere, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate each of your markers by looping through them and putting the labels as text annotations

```
for x, y, text in zip(list_of_rec, list_of_prec, list_of_markers):
    plt.text(x, y, text)
```

[image]